# How to find link behind Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, csv, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to access data from a government website, designed for "point-and-click" downloads. My objective is to find out what the pattern to get to CSVs, and then create an easy API for other people to get to that data.  The website is supposed to be open data, but is quite obscure as to how to get data programatically.

I have however failed to figure out what the pattern is to find a URL to the CSVs, because they seem to be hidden behind some JavaScript.

An example of a page is [this one](http://www.dados.gov.pt/PT/CatalogoDados/Dados.aspx?name=LocaisatendimentodaAPMJConservatorias), and I want to know what the link behind the png image on the page.

How can I programatically get to the links behind this button?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get to the links behind this button?

Investigate your web browser's "web developer" features.  There should be a way to get the browser to log the full URLs for all of the requests that it is making.

Then reverse engineer the pattern from the examples.  (This may or may not be possible.  But if it is not possible, you should let the people who designed the site that it is unfriendly to people trying to use it ... programatically.)

> How can I programatically get to the links behind this button?

Different question.  Here are some possible options:

- Use a web-scraping framework that understands how to execute Javascript as well.
- Use a web testing framework like Selenium
- There is a "headless browser" framework called Phantom.JS that may help.

Note that it is a lot more complicated to do this programatically.  If reverse engineering is possible, that would be simpler.